# Javascript prototype chain self reference

Tags: javascript, prototype

This question is about how javascript prototypes work.  In particular I do not understand why in the example below "Machine" appears to have a prototype of itself.

In the screen capture from Chrome Web Tools console the Machine __proto __ object seems to reference the same function as its parent.  You will see a "__proto __: Machine" with a property "whoAmI" and a second property "__proto __: Machine".  Drilling into this second "__proto __" reveals a constructor and the "__proto __" containing Object but no property "whoAmI".

What is the meaning of the double reference to "Machine" and why does only one of them contain the whoAmyI property?

```
function Car(){}

function Vehicle() {}

function Machine() {
    this.whoAmI = 'I am a machine';
}

Vehicle.prototype = new Machine();

Car.prototype = new Vehicle();

var myCar = new Car();
```

Chrome web tools screen capture:

[image: Chrome web tools screen capture]

Comment: That's just console output, so don't read too much into it. A preferred way to set up inheritance is to do `Vehicle.prototype = Object.create(Machine.prototype);`. Do this and you'll get different labels in Chrome's console, even though it's basically the same (though the `Vehicle.prototype` object won't have a `whoAmI` property).

Comment: I think part of the issue is that chrome uses the `.constructor` property to figure out the labels. The way you're setting up inheritance, you're destroying the original `.constructor` properties. If you do `Vechicle.prototype.constructor = Vehicle; Car.prototype.constructor = Car;`, you should get a more understandable output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use Object.create instead of creating an instance of Parent to set prototype of Child for (at least) 2 reasons.

1. When you define the Child type you may not want to create instances of Parent at this point due to the state of the application not being ready to create instances of Parent type at this point (like dependencies that need to be passed to the Parent constructor that are not available when defining Child).
2. Parent has instance specific members (any `this.something =` in Parent constructor) and creating an instance of Parent puts these instance specific members on Child.prototype.

That is why you see Machine (an instance of type Machine) with a whoAmi member and a Machine as the `__proto__` of this Machine instance.

The following code may produce output you'd expect and because the constructor is fixed after setting prototype part of inheritance it displays the right name:

```
function Car(){
  //re use parent constructor
  Vehicle.call(this);
  //extend whoAmi
  this.whoAmI = this.whoAmI + ' and a Car';
}

function Vehicle() {
  //re use parent constructor
  Machine.call(this);
  //extend whoAmi
  this.whoAmI = this.whoAmI + ' and a Vehicle';
}

function Machine() {
    this.whoAmI = 'I am a machine';
}

Vehicle.prototype = Object.create(Machine.prototype);
Vehicle.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;

var myCar = new Car();
console.dir(myCar);
```

Maybe the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711) can help understanding the role of prototype and constructor functions (or init) when creating instances of a certain type:

Comment: You can set the constructor all in one go with a second argument. `Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype, {constructor: value: Car}});`

Comment: @naomik correct but the second argument cannot be polyfilled in some browsers (ie8). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fcreate#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I'd agree with @naomik. As long as you're going to set the `.constructor`, might as well do it with one call. The second argument can be polyfilled. It's the `enumerable`, `writable` and `configurable` descriptors that can't be emulated.

Answer (score 1):

Shortish answer if I understand your question: It's not actually a self reference. When you define a function, the prototype property on it gets initialized to a new object with a `constructor` property that points to the function being defined.  You are overriding this prototype object on your `Vehicle` and `Car` functions, but not the `Machine` function.  For reasons I don't know, Chrome names the type of the default prototype property of a function the same as the name of the function.  IE refers to it as `[object (Machine)]` and Firefox just refers to it just as `Object`.

So to recap: `myCar` has `__proto__` set to `Car.prototype`, which is a `Vehicle` instance that has it's `__proto__` set to `Vehicle.prototype`, which is a `Machine` instance (with a `whoAmI` property) that has it's `__proto__` set to `Machine.prototype`, which is an object, with a `constructor` property, that Chrome (unfortunately? there must be a reason...) refers to with the same name as the function pointed to by the `constructor` property.

That is why there is that extra "Machine" object in there, but I can't tell you why Chrome calls it what it does.